# Color of communities in infomap algorithm python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I used this link [here](https://github.com/mapequation/infomap/blob/master/examples/python/infomap-networkx.py) as a reference to run infomap algorithm on a directed graph. But when the number of communities increases this algorithm cant show all communities with different colors (since the colors are given manually):

```
# color map from http://colorbrewer2.org/
cmap_light = colors.ListedColormap(
    ['#a6cee3', '#b2df8a', '#fb9a99', '#fdbf6f', '#cab2d6'], 'indexed', num_communities)
cmap_dark = colors.ListedColormap(
    ['#1f78b4', '#33a02c', '#e31a1c', '#ff7f00', '#6a3d9a'], 'indexed', num_communities)
```

If I detect the 10 largest communities setting colors like this won't be a problem! how can I choose the 10 largest communities after detecting them?

Comment: Well you would probably need some list of colours that has a length which matches the max value for num_communities right?

Comment: That's right! how can I do it?

Comment: Is there a set max value for num_communities and does it matter what colours are used or just that they have to be different?

Comment: No, there isn't any set max value but it would be good if I can only show the top 10 communities (in some cases there were more than 400 communities) and the colors don't matter.

Comment: Looking [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html) it looks like the list of colours is just repeated if `num_communities` is longer than the list of colours

Comment: So what exactly do you want to happen, just to be specific

Comment: I changed the question a bit. guess it's more clear now.

Comment: Sorry I tried to look for a solution but I don't have enough experience with this, hopefully someone with more knowledge can help out I've upvoted your question

Comment: I appreciate ur time and effort, Thank you!